# Why search bar shows blank even though it takes space of data received

Tags: angular

I'm creating a search option in angular. My issue is that my search data shows blank and it still takes the space of the data. I have check the API call and i see i got the data from API. So what might me the issue i'll share the code here.

```
<div class="custom_modal">
<h3 mat-dialog-title>Service Code</h3>
<div mat-dialog-content >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <mat-select placeholder="Service Code" (selectionChange)="onServiceCodeSelection($event)" matInput [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && formControls.serviceCode.errors }" required>
                            <ngx-mat-select-search placeholderLabel="Search" noEntriesFoundLabel="no match found" [formControl]="websiteMultiFilterCtrl1" ngDefaultControl>
                            </ngx-mat-select-search>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of masterServiceCode" [value]="option">
                                {{ option.value }}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="formControls.serviceCode.errors"> Please select service code </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" class="rounded px-1" (click)="closeDialog('close')">Close</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="rounded px-1" (click)="onAddServiceCode()">Add</button>
</div>
</div>
```

any probable issue here
here is the UI of my search bar
[image]

Comment: Likely caused by a typo. The blank spaces indicate, that the property `value` on option is undefined. Double check your data, maybe it is `Value`(capital v)?

Comment: I am almost certain, the objects you have in `masterServiceCode` do not have `value` field, thus nothing is populating on UI. Add a sample of `masterServiceCode` in your question, just HTML doesn't really help solving your issue.